# Imagick Animate Image Position

Tags: animation, imagick

I was curious on if there was a way to animate the position of an image in Imagick. So far I have this:

```
// Adding layer functionality
protected function createCanvas( $asset )
{
    // Create new imagick layer
    $layer = new Imagick( $asset );
    $layer->thumbnailImage( $this->width, $this->height );

    $layer->evaluateImage(Imagick::EVALUATE_DIVIDE, 1, Imagick::CHANNEL_ALPHA);

    return $layer;
}

// Create base layer
$im = new Imagick(); 
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->readImage( 'beginner-crate-back.png );
$im->setImageFormat("png32");

// Set base
$this->base = $im;

// Add image that needs positioning
$layer = $this->createCanvas( 'pet.png' );
$this->base->compositeImage( $layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 360, 170);

// Add top of cage
$layer = $this->createCanvas( 'beginner-crate-front.png' );
$this->base->compositeImage( $layer, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0 );

$final = $this->base->flattenImages();
```

So where I'm adding the image that needs positioning, I place it at 360 pixels to the right and 170 pixels to the bottom. However, I would like to animate so the top starts at 0 and slowly increases to 170 overtime. I didn't know if this was possible with Imagick since I need that bottom and top layer to stay consistent with every frame.

Thanks for any insight or help on how to achieve this! The pet image is dynamically generated so I can't animate that image as a GIF. That's not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

PNG does not support animation. And although your source image may be a PNG, you can still use it to make an animated GIF. e.g. something like:

```
function makeSimpleGif() {
    $aniGif = new \Imagick();
    $aniGif->setFormat("gif");

    $circleRadius = 20;
    $imageFrames = 40;
    $imageSize = 200;

    $background = new \Imagick();
    $background->newpseudoimage($imageSize, $imageSize, "plasma:tomato-steelblue");

    //$pet = new Imagick(realpath('pet.png'));
    //I don't have your pet image - but change it back here...
    $pet = new \Imagick();
    $pet->newpseudoimage(20, 20, "canvas:white");

    $moveDistance = 170;

    for($count=0 ; $count<$imageFrames ; $count++){
        $frame = clone $background;
        $x = 20;
        $y = 10 + ($moveDistance * ($count / $imageFrames)); 
        $frame->compositeImage($pet, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, $x, $y);
        $frame->setImageDelay(10);
        $aniGif->addImage($frame);
    }

    $aniGif = $aniGif->deconstructImages();

    return $aniGif;
}

$aniGif = makeSimpleGif();

$aniGif->writeImages("./aniOutput.gif", true);
```

Outputs an image like:

[image]

Make sure to use `writeImages` not the singular version when writing an animated gif file.

Comment: with that code, all I get is the background. The pet image never shows.

Comment: all i get is the bunny overlayed on the background. sorry had the dimensions off last time... however the bunny doesn't move it seems.

Comment: I clarified to use `writeImages`